# get_queryset vs manager in Django

Tags: django

As far as I know, we bring the database by model managers right?

e.g. `queryset = Model.objects.all()`

But sometimes, I see some code that seems almost same thing but is  a bit different,

`post = self.get_queryset()`

which also fetches database but not by manager.

What's the difference between fetching database by manager and get_queryset() and their usage?

Comment: Are you talking about class based views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below example helps you to understand what `ModelManager` and `get_queryset` are:

```
class PersonQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def authors(self):
        return self.filter(role='A')

    def editors(self):
        return self.filter(role='E')

class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PersonQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def authors(self):
        return self.get_queryset().authors()

    def editors(self):
        return self.get_queryset().editors()

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=(('A', _('Author')), ('E', _('Editor'))))
    people = PersonManager()
```

Every model have at least one model manager and `get_queryset` is the model manager base `QuerySet`.
When you use `Person.objects.all()` it will return all results from `Person` model, not filters or anything else.

In the above example, we use a custom model manager named `PersonManager`, where we override `get_queryset`.
Firstly, we apply `authors` filter with `role='A'`.
Secondly, we apply `editors` filter with `role='E'`.

So, now if we use `Person.people.all()` it will return only `authors`. Look here we use `all()` but it returns only `authors`. Because we override the Default model manager queryset.